# HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=4444)

Tags: python, docker, selenium, selenium-hub

i need run my script in docker container

```
version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.0.0-rc-1-prerelease-20210823
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
    ports:
      - "6900:5900"

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.0.0-rc-1-prerelease-20210823
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
   app:
        build:
            context: . 
        volumes:
            - . :/home/saimon/
        network_mode: "host"
        depends_on:
            - selenium-hub
            - chrome
        command:
            python3 app.py
        environment:
            - SELENIUM_REMOTE_HOST=selenium-hub
```

in my app  i:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub',
                                           desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME, options=self.chrome_options)
```

i make:
docker-compose build

sudo docker-compose run --rm app
or
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up

and show this error:

> urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='selenium-hub', port=4444): Max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fa7f86b3700>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))

Comment: I added links: selenium-hub on my Chrome service and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Remove `network_mode: "host"` if you want to be able to connect to `http://selenium-hub:4444` from the app container

You should also try using the env-var

```
import os 

host = os.environ['SELENIUM_REMOTE_HOST']
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://{}:4444/wd/hub'.format(host),
  ...
```

Comment: I need wait browser up!

Comment: That's what `depends_on:chrome` in the compose file does. If your app starts faster than selenium, then add a sleep function in your code